# Dependência do JPA(2.1) no arquivo POM.xml

Tags: java, maven, persistência, pom

Fiz um projeto JavaSE normal com o JPA para a parte de persistência, e deu certo, o projeto consiste apenas de uma entidade que é persistida no banco e nada mais. Usei as seguintes bibliotecas:

- EclipseLink(JPA 2.1) - eclipselink.jar
- EclipseLink(JPA 2.1) - javax.persistence_2.1.0v201304241213.jar
- EclipseLink(JPA 2.1)
  -org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.5.2v20140319-9ad6abd.jar
- Driver JDBC do PostgresSQL -postgresql-92-1002.jdbc4.jar

  Mas quando tentei fazer o mesmo projeto Java no Maven, deu uma zebra, não consigo colocar todas as dependências!.
  Aqui esta um trecho das dependências que consegui encontrar:

  ```
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.0</version>
          <type>jar</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
          <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
          <version>9.2-1002-jdbc4</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  ```

Mas ainda faltam as outras duas bibliotecas. O que devo fazer?

Sempre aparece este erro quando tento executar o projeto:

*Failed to execute goal on project JPA_TESTE: Could not resolve dependencies for project exemplo.jpa:JPA_TESTE:jar:1.0: Failure to find org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.1 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]*

Estou usando o netbeans e tentando fazer uma projeto javaSE maven a aplicação completa esta no [github](http://github.com/WellingtonLins/JPA_TESTE).

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003421/how-to-setup-eclipselink-with-jpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se são essas que você quer.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: A segunda dá pra gente tentar outra dependência. Espera aí 1 min.

Comment: Tenta mudar a versão do eclipselink para `<version>2.5.0</version>`. Vê se funciona.

Comment: Se for o caso, baixa o jar daqui: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.5.0

Comment: E aí, funcionou?

Comment: Mas vc chegou a baixar o jar no link que te mostrei? Se for só o jar do eclipselink que está faltando, vai resolver baixando. Claro que depois que baixar, vc tem que pôr no path do eclipse.

Comment: eu uso o netbeans e já baixei todas as dependências!! Mesmo deu um erro!! é uma plicação javaSE com o maven !